# Triple integral changing order of integration(impossible textbook question)

Tags: calculus, integration

[Related to the question here:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780620/graphing-a-triple-integral-software-and-the-actual-integral)

> can anyone see this post, please help or atleast comment, I can't go on in the textbook the next three problems have the same issue!! I don't understand the upvotes and no answers

$$ \int_0^1 \int_\sqrt{z}^1 \int_0^{2-y-z} f(x,y,z) \; \mathrm{d}x\; \mathrm{d}y\; \mathrm{d}z$$

I want to change that order to $\mathrm{d}z\; \mathrm{d}x\; \mathrm{d}y$
${}$
Now I have:
$$R = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid (0 \le z \le 1) \wedge (z \le y^2 \le 1) \wedge (0 \le x+y+z \le 2)\}.$$

But because of the order, I have both $y \leq y^2$ and $ z \leq 2-y-x$, so I have set up my attempt as $R = \{{(x,y,z)|0\leq y \leq 1,0 \leq x\leq 2-y,0\leq z \leq y^2}\}$, but this is missing a bounding, and I don't know what to do. Please help me!

Note: Just the bounds for the region as the function is not known.

Breaking into two regions:

I don't have any software to confirm my two regions as encompassing the total region.
1: $0 \leq y \leq 1, 0 \leq x \leq 2-y, 0 \leq z \leq y^2$

and 2: $0 \leq y \leq 1, 0 \leq x \leq 2-y, 0 \leq z \leq 2-x-y$

Is this question impossible, no-one here can work it out , so I assume the textbook did it as a trick.

> Why is this question impossible to set up as triple integrals?

[image]

*Image courtesy of @heropup*

Comment: The requested change in the order of integration is not straightforward.  Doing so will require splitting up the integral into a minimum of three pieces, along the curve in the $xy$-plane defined by $x = 2-y-y^2$, and also along the line segment joining $(1,\tfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2})$ to $(1,1)$.

Comment: @heropup are you saying I can't have a single triple integral? I haven't encountered this before, do I need a double and a single disjoint? Sorry, I am relatively new to this, thank you for your time.

Comment: Unless you want to use complicated piecewise-defined functions to specify the limits of integration, it is not possible to express the given integral as a single triple integral with the requested integration order.  Study the region of integration carefully.

Comment: @heropup I don't have any software to confirm my two regions as encompassing the total region.
1: $0 \leq y \leq 1, 0 \leq x \leq 2-y, 0 \leq z \leq y^2$

and 2: $0 \leq y \leq 1, 0 \leq x \leq 2-y, 0 \leq z \leq 2-x-y$

Is this correct?

Comment: As Heropup stated, you will need to break it across three regions, which you can see clearly by the image he generated for you in the previous question you posted(which he linked above).

Comment: In your first expression for $R$, you translated the bounds on the integral on $x$ incorrectly.

Comment: @hurkyl did I ? This is for x leq 2-y? That should be right though because z=0? Right?

Comment: @Katie: No, I mean that the very first expression should have been $0 \leq x \leq 2 - y -z$, or equivalently, $y+z \leq x + y + z \leq 2$

Comment: @hurkyl wow true , heropup made that mistake and I didn't see it. I still don't know how to change the order at all sadly

Comment: @heropup What software did you utilize in creating the image displayed by that gif?

Comment: I used Mathematica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your domain $R\subset{\mathbb R}^3$ is defined by the following three conditions:
$$({\rm a})\quad 0\leq z\leq1,\qquad({\rm b})\quad \sqrt{z}\leq y\leq 1,\qquad({\rm c})\quad 0\leq x\leq 2-y-z\ .$$
The second condition is equivalent with
$$({\rm b}')\qquad 0\leq y\leq 1\quad\wedge\quad z\leq y^2\ .$$
[image]

It follows that $R$ is a subset of the simplex $$S:=\bigl\{(x,y,z)\bigm| x\geq0,\ y\geq0,\ z\geq0, \ x+y+z\leq2\bigr\}$$
shown in the above figure; see also heropup's figure shown as an appendix to the question. Simple extra conditions are $y\leq1$ and $z\leq1$, but most notorious is $z\leq y^2$, indicating that admissible points $(x,y,z)$ have to lie below the parabolic cylinder $z=y^2$. This cylinder intersects the oblique facet of $S$ in the curve
$$\gamma:\quad y\mapsto (x,y,z):=(2-y-y^2, y, y^2)\qquad(0\leq y\leq1)\ ,$$
and this curve projects vertically down onto the curve
$$\gamma':\quad x\mapsto(x,y):=(2-y-y^2,y)\qquad(0\leq y\leq1)\ ,$$
resp.
$$\gamma':\quad x\mapsto(x,y):=\left(x,{\sqrt{9-4x}-1\over2}\right)\qquad(0\leq x\leq2)\ ,$$
shown in blue in the figure.

The vertical stalk erected on points $(x,y)$ to the left of $\gamma'$ ends on the cylinder $z=y^2$, and the stalk erected on points to the right of $\gamma'$ ends on the facet $z=2-x-y$ of $S$. It follows that we have to foresee three triple integrals when the integration order has to be $\ \ldots dz\>dy\>dx$, namely
$$\eqalign{&\int_0^2\int_0^{(\sqrt{9-4x}-1)/2}\int_0^{y^2}\ldots dz\>dy\>dx \quad +\cr
&\int_0^1\int_{(\sqrt{9-4x}-1)/2}^1\int_0^{2-y-x}\ldots dz\>dy\>dx \quad+\cr
&\int_1^2\int_{(\sqrt{9-4x}-1)/2}^{2-x}\int_0^{2-y-x}\ldots dz\>dy\>dx\quad.\cr} $$

Comment: What software was used to generate the above figure?

Comment: @Display Name: I use the drawing program Canvas since aeons. The curves $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ in the figure were drawn by hand and are not mathematically defined.

Comment: Very nice, looks better than many of the newer modelling tools I have seen!